# DocuSaurus - Automatic JavaScript documentation

Tags: javascript, markdown, documentation, jsdoc, docusaurus

Is there a plugin or library that can be used to convert JavaScript code and comments into documentation in DocuSaurus?

The only option I found was using `jsdoc-to-markdown`, and I would like to know if there are other options.

I'm looking to something that can generate a navigation menu too, like how [DocDash](http://clenemt.github.io/docdash/) does.

Comment: Please review what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. Questions asking us to find or recommend an off-site resource, like a library or plugin, are explicitly _off-topic_ as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.